# Get relation data on comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I am an average in database operation but I never deal with a database having values in comma separated manner. As I want the result from both table.

I have one table **"Form table"**

```
+------+-----------------+
| id   | Fname           |
+------+-----------------+
| 1    | f_934_tarun1    |
| 2    | f_934_tarun2    |
| 3    | f_934_a1        |
+------+-----------------+
```

2nd table **"user assigned form table"**

```
+------+--------------------------------+
| u_id | Fname                          |
+------+--------------------------------+
| 1    | f_934_xyz,f_934_tarun1         |
| 2    | f_934_tarun2,f_934_fhh         |
| 3    | f_934_ttt,f_934_nhj            |
| 4    | f_934_a1,f_934_t5trt           |
+------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to get all user ids who has any of form listed in form table. So here the output will be:

```
+------+
| u_id |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 4    |
+------+
```

Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) to achieve this:

```
SELECT U.u_id
FROM Userassigned U
JOIN FormTable F ON INSTR(U.Fname, F.Fname) > 0;
```

SQL Fiddle for the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f27ce/1

Comment: @DeepakSharma: Glad to help, you are welcome.